# Angular2 Notify Component Of Data Change

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

So I've been working my way through the Angular 2 tutorials and documentation. While playing around with it, I wanted to see if I can separate the form into its own component but still work the same way; when you add a hero, it automatically adds them to the list. I have the list as the parent component and the form as the child component. At the moment, when you add a hero, it gets added to the data, but the list isn't automatically updated. However, if you navigate to the dashboard and then back to the list, the hero is now there.

Here's my list component:

```
import { Component, OnInit }    from '@angular/core';
import { Router }               from '@angular/router';

import { Hero }                 from './hero';
import { HeroFormComponent }    from './hero-form.component';
import { HeroService }          from './hero.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-heroes',
    templateUrl:'app/heroes.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/heroes.component.css'],
    providers: [HeroService],
    directives: [HeroFormComponent]
})

export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
    heroes: Hero[];
    selectedHero: Hero;

    constructor(private router: Router, private heroService: HeroService) {}

    delete(hero: Hero): void {
        this.heroService
            .delete(hero.id)
            .then(() => {
                this.heroes = this.heroes.filter(h => h !== hero);
                if(this.selectedHero === hero) { this.selectedHero = null; }
            });
    }

    getHeroes(): void {
        this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getHeroes();
    }

    onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
        if(this.selectedHero === hero) {
            this.selectedHero = null;
        } else {
            this.selectedHero = hero;
        }
    }

    gotoDetail(): void {
        this.router.navigate(['/detail', this.selectedHero.id]);
    }
}
```

Here's my form component:

```
import { Component, Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Hero }                     from './hero';
import { HeroService }              from './hero.service';
import { HeroesComponent }          from './heroes.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'hero-form',
    templateUrl: 'app/hero-form.component.html',
    providers: [HeroService]
})

@Injectable()
export class HeroFormComponent {

    heroes: Hero[] = [];

    constructor(private heroService: HeroService) {}

    add(name: string, heroName: HTMLInputElement): void {

        name = name.trim();
        if (!name) { return; }

        this.heroService.create(name)
            .then(hero => {
                this.heroes.push(hero);
                this.selectedHero = null;
            });

        heroName.value = null;

    }
}
```

Here's my service:

```
import { Injectable }       from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http }    from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Hero } from './hero';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

    private heroesUrl = 'app/heroes';
    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    create(name: string): Promise<Hero> {
        return this.http
                   .post(this.heroesUrl, JSON.stringify({name: name}), {headers: this.headers})
                   .toPromise()
                   .then(res => res.json().data)
                   .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    delete(id: number): Promise<void> {
        let url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${id}`;
        return this.http.delete(url, {headers: this.headers})
                   .toPromise()
                   .then(() => null)
                   .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {
        return this.getHeroes()
                   .then(heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === id));
    }

    getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                   .toPromise()
                   .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
                   .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    update(hero: Hero): Promise<Hero> {
        const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${hero.id}`;
        return this.http
                   .put(url, JSON.stringify(hero), {headers: this.headers})
                   .toPromise()
                   .then(() => hero)
                   .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

What needs to be done so the list component recognizes the data update and refreshes the actual list?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing tying the Heroes that are present on the server to the Heroes present on the client, so when the contents on the server change (when you add to them using the form) it becomes de-synced from the list on the client.  They get temporarily back in sync when you re-navigate to the HeroesComponent because you call getHeroes() again.  You need a way to notify the HeroesComponent about changes in the data.

You are currently using Promises for async communication, but that won't be good enough since Promises are one-and-done while you need a continuous update, preferably pushed from the service.  For that you need Observable.  You might register as an Observer on the service's heroes in the HeroesComponent ngOnInit() and deregister in the ngOnDestroy().  The service would need to send out the heroes list when getHeroes() is called, but would also need to re-send when a hero is added, removed, or edited.

Answer (score 0):

issue is you are resolving the heroes hence any further updates are not reflected,

**service**

```
heroes: Subject<Hero[]> = new Subject<Hero[]>();

getHeroes(){
    this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => {
                    this.heroes.next(response.json().data as Hero[]);
               })
               .catch(this.handleError);
}

create(name: string): Promise<Hero> {
    return this.http
               .post(this.heroesUrl, JSON.stringify({name: name}), {headers: this.headers})
               .toPromise()
               .then(res => {
                 // update heroes observable
                 this.getHeroes();
                 return res.json().data
              })
               .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**HeroesComponent**

```
getHeroes(): void {
        this.heroes = this.heroService.heroes;
        this.heroService.getHeroes();
    }
```

in HTML template add a `async` pipe which will help resolve promise and will update list for future update.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: At first I got an error for Subject not being defined which I cleared up by adding this import to the service:

import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

On the list page I'm now getting no results. However, the hero is being added to the list as they appear on the dashboard page. There are no errors on the list page.

Added this to the list page but wan't sure if I'm using it correctly: *ngFor="let hero of heroes | async"

Comment: yes, that is correct, you may read more about [AsyncPipe here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-class.html)

Comment: Any insight as to why the list would be empty now?

Comment: something to do with your service may be? have you checked if it is returning value? Log `response.json().data` if it has values.

Comment: I get an array of hero objects which also updates every time I add one.

[Object, Object, Object]

Comment: can you reproduce your issue in Plunker?

Comment: The getHeroes() function is running in the service each time a change is made. However, the component getHeroes() function only runs after the page is loaded.